# Ignore all invalid records while copy data from s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm copying billions of records from s3(multiple files) to redshift table, where there are invalid records. I want to ignore all invalid records while copy data from s3 to redshift. But when I check "MAXERROR" limit is "100000". But in my case total number of invalid records are greater than "100000". Is there way to ignore all invalid records while copy data to redshift table?

But in my case, per s3 file invalid records won't be grater than "100000". If I configure "MAXERROR" per file then I can solve this problem but I didn't find any reference for this ?

Is it possible to configure "MAXERROR" per file? If not, Is there any other alternative way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`MAXERROR` is checked per copy command, and because of the parallel nature of Amazon Redshift it allows you to process multiple S3 files in parallel for faster loading but all copying nodes share singleton `MAXERROR` value asynchronously. Of course there is expected inconsistency when running parallel, and that's why AWS guide states this for actual ERROR_COUNT may exceed way beyond MAXERROR.

> > The actual number of errors reported might be greater than the specified MAXERROR because of the parallel nature of Amazon Redshift. If any node in the Amazon Redshift cluster detects that MAXERROR has been exceeded, each node reports all of the errors it has encountered.

**TLDR;** To answer your question in short: No you can't define `MAXERROR` per S3 file. 
But to achieve your **desired result**, you can break down your load into multiple copy command & processing smaller chunks of S3 files at a time by [`key_prefix`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html#tutorial-loading-key-prefix).